# Fancybox AJAX - how to close dialog after postback

Tags: ajax, postback, fancybox

I have a link on my ShowData.aspx page that I'm calling fancybox on.

`<a href="EditData.aspx" id="editLink">Edit Data</a>`

My JQuery code is:

```
$("#editLink").fancybox({
                        'opacity': true,
                        'overlayShow': true,
                        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                        'transitionOut': 'none'                                                        
                    });
```

The form EditData.aspx contains a save button. My problem is that after I click the save button the dialog does not close. Furthermore, after the save is performed on the server the client page redirects to EditData.aspx.

The expected outcome is that the dialog closes and I am returned to the parent page (ShowData.aspx).

Thanks!

Comment: Check your console. I bet there's an error elsewhere in your script.

Comment: Does that mean what I have is suppose to work as described? Don't I have to wire up the "close dialog" after the post back occurs? I'll check my console.

Comment: No console errors. I also noticed that the datepicker control does not work either. None of the JQuery stuff in EditData.aspx works when hosted in an ajax dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an iFrame. This seems to do the job.

MainPage.aspx

```
<div id="divClick"><iframe src="Postback.aspx"></iframe></div>
```

JQuery:

```
 $(function () {
       $("#divClick").dialog({
          modal: true,                
          title: 'iFrame Page',
          width: 500,
          height: 500
       });
   });
```

JQuery plugins in Postback.aspx work well and posting back doesn't close the dialog and redirect the main page.

Answer (score 0):

I removed fancybox and found that this issue also occurs with regular JQuery dialogs. If you load a page that has a submit button (or posts back in any way) then your dialog will disappear and your main page will redirect to the dialog page. Here's a simple test:

HTML:

```
<div id="divClick"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
            $("#divClick").dialog({
                modal: true,
                open: function () {
                    $(this).load('Postback.aspx');
                },
                title: 'Ajax Page'
            });
        });
```

Postback.aspx:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    Enter Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Is there a way to attach an event to the postback from the dialog?

Furthermore, I modified Postback.aspx to include jscolor.js (a JQuery plugin) to see if it would work, it did not work. Any JQuery functionality doesn't seem to work in a dialog.